# Is it possible to generate a dll with android ndk for testing purposes?

Tags: android, dll, android-ndk, robolectric, android-testing

I am developing an app which uses a native library. I would like to test it using a non-android dependent framework like Robolectric.

The problem is, that the native functionality cannot be loaded using

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

because on Windows it looks for "mylib.dll", and I am only able to build libmylib.so which is not compatible with windows.

Is there a way to build a dll (it would be only used for testing purposes ofc)?

Comment: what exactly do you want to test? Would be c++ unit tests enough for your purposes?

Comment: i would like to test the code without using an actual device / emulator without mocking all the native functionality

Comment: Robolectric currently does not support running externally written native code. If you access any such code, it gives an UnsatisfiedLinkError

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your application on windows, then you need a *.dll. *.so files are unix "shared libraries" - same functionality as windows' dll.
You have to build your C++ sources with an IDE like Visual Studio, Code Blocks, or anything else that can build sources for windows.

In fact, when building with "ndk-build" for android, you are [cross-compiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_compiler) for an Unix system with an ARM architecture mostly.
When running on windows, you'll probably be on x86 / x86_64.